# '\n' creates an indentation while parsing python code with ast.parse

Tags: python, parsing, indentation, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to parse with ast.parse in Python 3.7 (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) the following snippet of code :

```
from functools import reduce 
reduce(lambda x, y: 10 * x + y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I use the code below :

```
py_ast = """from functools import reduce \n reduce(lambda x, y: 10 * x + y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])"""

py_ast = ast.parse(py_ast)
```

And i got this error :

> File "", line 2
> --> reduce(lambda x, y: 10 * x + y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
> IndentationError: unexpected indent

I understand the use of `\n` is creating an indent, how can I avoid it?

Comment: by using double slashes `\\n`

Comment: You have an indent -- there's a space before `reduce`.

Comment: using double slashes give me `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

Comment: Removing the space before `reduce` gives me the following code : `from functools import reduce`, a part is missing

Comment: no, before the *other* `reduce`. Look at it closely. `from functools import reduce \n reduce`. Zoom in: `\n reduce`. See how there is a space between `\n` and `reduce`? Imagine if you were to `print` this string. Do you see how this would put a space at the front of the second line?

Comment: Hint: try `print(py_ast)` before the `ast.parse` call. Notice anything off? How would you solve that problem, if it were the actual source code in a `.py` file you were writing?

Answer (score 2):

You're using triple quotes so why not leave out the \n altogether and just hit enter, the string will stay formatted how you want it.

This code runs fine for me:

```
import ast

py_ast = """from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x, y: 10 * x + y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])"""

py_ast = ast.parse(py_ast)

print(py_ast)
>>> <ast.Module object at 0x0000019F2E140FD0>
```

Comment: Then again, removing the space before \n also runs fine for me. What's the error you're getting when you do that?

Comment: It's strange, when I'm doing that, I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathanael/Desktop/NL2CODE/asdl/ast_operation.py", line 168, in <module>
    py_ast = ast.parse(py_ast)
  File "/Users/nathanael/opt/anaconda3/envs/NL2CODE/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 2
    reduce(lambda x, y: 10 * x + y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Comment: But when I'm running your code in python console, I don't have any problem

Comment: Weird, do you have different versions of python? Maybe vscode is using a different version to the one you use when you're on the console. Not sure how you'd be getting that error though. Have you had any other weird problems like that with specifically vscode?

Comment: I'm using Pycharm, but I checked, I got the same version in my console and project. I don't have a clue what is happening

Comment: Sorry don't know why  I assumed haha. I do find pycharm to have some odd bugs sometimes. If you make a new project and try the same code do you still have that issue? Otherwise check if you need to update pycharm version or maybe even rollback. Sorry it seems like pycharm itself is the issue here

Comment: Same issue with a new project. You must be right, it's Pycharm fault. I will try to fix it, thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem hope it works out, random inexplicable bugs are rough to deal with